# Find text between two json keys using regex

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a json text file which contains keys with "text": "Some text","submitted_by": so on.. However I'm looking to

```
{"data": [{ "id": "", "text": "some text", "submitted_at": ""} , {..}, {..}]}
```

I'm looking to get the "some text part" from each record as well as the ID part. I've tried the following :

```
for matchedtext in re.findall(r'(?<=text":").*?(?=","submitted_at)', line):
     print(matchedtext)

re.findall(r'"text":"(.*?)"', line)
```

Actual data corrected :
{"data": [{ "id":"", "text":"some text", "submitted_at":""} , {..}, {..}]}

Comment: It looks like a json string, why not just use `json.loads(line)` & access by keys.

Comment: I want to do it with Regex!

Comment: @EmmaVaze Another JSON file might put the dictionary keys in a different order. What sushanth suggested is so much the obvious and correct way to extract this data.

Answer (score 0):

Given this line:

```
line = '{"data": [{ "id": "id1", "text": "some text", "submitted_at": ""}, { "id": "id2", "text": "some other text", "submitted_at": ""}]}'
```

You should really parse this as JSON. Bear in mind that the dictionary keys might not always be written in the same order.

```
import json

for record in json.loads(line)['data']:
    print('ID:', record['id'], 'TEXT:', record['text'])
```

But if you really must use regexp, then yes, I suppose it can be done...

```
import re

pattern = '"id":\s*"(.*?)",.*?"text":\s*"(.*?)"'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
    print('ID:', match.group(1), 'TEXT:', match.group(2))
```

Output in each case:

```
ID: id1 TEXT: some text
ID: id2 TEXT: some other text
```

Comment: Yes. Looking for  regex approach knowing Json would be better for a requirement. But when I check with my data I found that there is no space between key and value i.e.  "id":"val1","text":"some text". How do I correct the above regex for it?

Comment: @EmmaVaze Now changed so that the spaces in the regexp are replaced by `\s*` (any amount of whitespace, including none at all).